# Create optimalisation matrix in python from different numbers and different size of list, which are included in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations, element

I am searching for a method to create a configuration list from dictionary. For example:

```
   Estimators = {'Model1':{'val1':(1,2), 'val2':(a,b)},
                 'Model2':{'val1':(1,2), 'val2':(a,b), 'val3'=(x,y)}}
```

Result need to be one list, contain all the possible combination in the 'Models':

```
(1,a)
(1,b)
(2,a)
(2,b)
(1,a,x)
(1,a,y)
...
```

I need a flexible method where the 'Estimators' can contain different size of 'Models' and the 'Models' can contain different numbers and sizes of the list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product, combinations
from itertools import chain

models = set(chain.from_iterable((v.values() for v in Estimators.values())))    
result = []
for i in range(2, len(models) + 1):
    for n in combinations(models, i):
        result.extend(list(product(*n)))

result
```

output:

```
[(1, 'x'),
 (1, 'y'),
 (2, 'x'),
 (2, 'y'),
 (1, 'a'),
 (1, 'b'),
 (2, 'a'),
 (2, 'b'),
 ('x', 'a'),
 ('x', 'b'),
 ('y', 'a'),
 ('y', 'b'),
 (1, 'x', 'a'),
 (1, 'x', 'b'),
 (1, 'y', 'a'),
 (1, 'y', 'b'),
 (2, 'x', 'a'),
 (2, 'x', 'b'),
 (2, 'y', 'a'),
 (2, 'y', 'b')]
```